# OnTextChanged searching listview

Tags: vb.net

I use a textbox to search a listview table, onText_changed i have:

```
Private Sub txtBoxSearchSearches_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtBoxSearchSearches.TextChanged
    listViewShowLinks.BeginUpdate()
    If (txtBoxSearchSearches.Text.Trim().Length = 0) Then
        listViewShowLinks.Items.Clear()
        For Each item In listCopy
            listViewShowLinks.Items.Add(item)
        Next
    Else
        listViewShowLinks.Items.Clear()
        For Each item In listCopy
            If (item.Text.Contains(txtBoxSearchSearches.Text)) Then
                listViewShowLinks.Items.Add(item)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    listViewShowLinks.EndUpdate()
End Sub
```

Which works well, the issue is, it only searches the data typed in from the first column in the listview, but i'm looking to use column #8, i'm not sure the best way to go about it.

any help would be appreciated :)

cheers

Graham

Comment: Since you are doing more than just searching, are you sure you want that firing basically on  a keypress?  To search column 8 compare to subitem(8) not item text

Comment: Just iterate the item.SubItems collection.

Comment: Thanks Hans staring me in the face lol

Answer (score 0):

You can references those items specifically by using something like the following:

```
for i = 0 to listview1.coulmns(7).Items.Count - 1
'Do whatever you need with the below.
ListView1.Columns(7).Items(i).text
Next
```